# Как исправить проблему скрола?

Tags: javascript, html, css

выдает в консоли (локально вижу)

jquery.nicescroll.min.js:2 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
codepen.io/Olya097/pen/RwMeLjR

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я дам совет о котором никто не просил, но лучше не использовать плагины для плавного скролла в принципе. В некоторых браузерах они криво отрабатывают, а на macos и IOS работают безбожно ужасно т.к. в системе есть свой плавный скролл.

API Chrome не дает корректно считывать прокрутку колеса мыши